# WebStorm Mocha Testing: tests never finish

Tags: mocha.js, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2017.2.2 to develop and run some `mocha` tests.

All is going pretty well, but the tests never finish. It gets done with running all of my test files, then just sits there spinning saying "Running Tests."

If I hover over the red box, it shows a tooltip that says: `Stop 'Full Tests' (`<kbd>⌘F2</kbd>`)`. It also shows "Stop Process" at the bottom of the IDE. So, I click it, and the red box turns into a skull.

Now, if I hover over the skull, it shows a tooltip that says: `Stop 'Full Tests' (`<kbd>⌘F2</kbd>`)` (same as before). It also shows "Kill Process" (different) at the bottom of the IDE. So, I click it, and the IDE stops saying "Running Tests" and now says "Test Results."

How do I configure WebStorm so that it automatically ties up those loose ends when it reaches the end of my test suite?

Comment: Unfamiliar with WebStorm so I will put this a comment first. Do the mocha test finish correctly? That could happen if you are doing some background test or working with promises and not calling done() in mocha.

Comment: @sfratini I think so. I'm still new to mocha, but when I run it from the CLI, all tests finish. Even there, though, I have to end the tests/server using Ctrl+C. I think I could use process.exit(0), but it would have to always be in my last test, and that seem unreliable to me. (I'm using the -S option, but I might add a new last test file.) Is there a standard mocha best practice for wrapping everything up? I've googled that a lot and can't find how everyone else is handling this, but I have to believe it's a common issue.

Comment: You shouldn't have to finish the process as mocha should finish on its own. Could you post your mocha file? Specially if you have promises.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue, I have removed all tests but 1 and still have the same problem, used to work fine!

Comment: I realize this is a year old post, but I had the same problem with WebStorm and found that I had specified the --watch flag. Removing this flag causes my tests to exit when done.

Answer (score 10):

To answer this, the mocha docs state that autoexit is not a feature in v4, basically something is stopping the tests from exiting, to revert back to the v3+ way of exiting when your tests pass, use the arg --exit in your test configs under Extra mocha options

https://boneskull.com/mocha-v4-nears-release/#mochawontforceexit